# Is there a way to import a function from another notebook into AWS EMR notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I would like to know if it is possible to import a function in one notebook into another in AWS EMR. While there are ways to import one notebook into another in typical jupyter notebooks, this does not appear to be the case in  jupyter notebooks hosted in EMR.

As a result of this behaviour I have to recreate the same function again in each notebook that requires the function creating many versions of the same code.

Comment: Could you try EMR release label 5.29 or 5.28 and see if it works?

Comment: @ParagChaudhari and how this is solved at 5.29?

Comment: It's not... I even tried on 6.xx EMR is broken and can't detect files. I used import-ipynb, just ipynb for import, plain import, nothing works